# Use existing graphql api in my laravel project

Tags: laravel, graphql

I am testing a graphql api and I want to integrate with my system in laravel. Is there any documentation to do this? If possible to consume and send the values ​​in graphql?

Note: I wanted to do it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is too generic.

First of all, I recommend to check the official site: https://graphql.org/learn/

If you are going to consume an already existing graphql, you need a graphql client library.

Check a good list of client libraries: https://graphql.org/code/#graphql-clients

Client libraries have good documentation on how to install and use them.

If you are going to create/provide your own graphql api endpoint (that is a different story), you need a graphql server library.

Server libraries: https://graphql.org/code/#php

Laravel package (a wrapper for https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php): https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel

Comment: "The question is too generic." sorry...
it's hard to ask questions if you don't know, but it's the client that I need.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this library https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel, it's simple with good documentation